# How can I get the request URL from a Java Filter?

Tags: java, url, servlet-filters

I am trying to write a filter that can retrieve the request URL, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException { }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getPathTranslated();
        System.out.println("Url: " + url);
    }

    public void destroy() { }
}
```

When I hit a page on my server, the only output I see is "Url: null".

What is the correct way to get the requested URL from a given ServletRequest object in a Filter?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
 String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
 String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();
}
```

To Reconstruct:

```
System.out.println(url + "?" + queryString);
```

Info on [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) and [`HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29).

Comment: `getRequestURL()` returns `StringBuffer`, not `String`.

Comment: It's better to consider the pattern of null `queryString`.

Comment: if you want the "http://blabla:8080" part stripped away for you, getRequestURI() ('I' not 'l') returns a String starting with "/"

Comment: If you want only the path to the servlet you can use `request.getServletPath()`, it's useful on JavaServer Faces to retrieve the equivalent of the view id (the path from the webapp root to the xhtml page, excluding domains, deployment prefix, etc)

Answer (score 6):

Building on [another answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389627/26510),

```
public static String getCurrentUrlFromRequest(ServletRequest request)
{
   if (! (request instanceof HttpServletRequest))
       return null;

   return getCurrentUrlFromRequest((HttpServletRequest)request);
}

public static String getCurrentUrlFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();

    if (queryString == null)
        return requestURL.toString();

    return requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Spring, you can use `OncePerRequestFilter` or others.

```java
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
         String url = request.getRequestURL();
         filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to acquire them separately you can use as the following

```
((HeaderWriterFilter.HeaderWriterRequest) request).getRequest().getAttribute("org.apache.catalina.AccessLog.ServerName") => host info
((HeaderWriterFilter.HeaderWriterRequest) request).getRequest().getAttribute("org.apache.catalina.AccessLog.ServerPort") => port info
((HttpServletRequest)request).getServletPath() or ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI() => requested source path
((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString() => query parameters
```

Answer (score -2):

```
request.getRequestURL();
```

- [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29)

Comment: ServletRequest does not implement getRequestURL().  You need to cast it to HttpServletRequest if possible as per Buhake's answer

Comment: its missing parameters