# How Can i show urls clicked by user in Primefaces+JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF2 with Prime faces. I will want to show all the previous links or Urls clicked by user in every page.How can i do this?

Comment: You're looking for a breadcrumb: http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/breadCrumb.jsf You'll have to put the logic in yourself.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but i am not looking for BreadCrumb..I have to show all Urls visited by user .Let us suppose if You Visited three Urls Like(A.xhtml,B.Xhtml,C.xhtml) and now You are in D.xhtml page then I have to Show Previous Three Urls to user.

Comment: I would probably use a filter to scrape the URL each time the user goes to a new page. That seems like the 'easiest' method. You can look at the Filter documentation. It is very straightforward.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi I have created this Singleton class to put the Url Browsed by a User.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class UrlHistory {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static Map<String, List> store = new HashMap<String, List>();

    private static UrlHistoryBean instance = null;


    public static UrlHistoryBean getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UrlHistoryBean();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    LinkedList<UrlData> urlList = new LinkedList<UrlHistoryBean.UrlData>();

    public void addUrl(String sessionId, String urlString, int urlId) {
        UrlData data = new UrlData();
        data.setUrlName(urlString);
        data.setUrlId(companyId);
        if (urlList.isEmpty()) {
            urlList.add(data);
        } else {
            boolean isEqual = false;
            for (UrlData urlDataObj : urlList) {
                if (urlDataObj.equals(data))
                    isEqual = true;
            }
            if(!isEqual)

                urlList.addFirst(data);
        }
        store.put(sessionId, urlList);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static Map<String, List> getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void setStore(Map<String, List> store) {
        UrlHistoryBean.store = store;
    }

    public class UrlData {

        String urlName;
        int urlId;

        public String getUrlName() {
            return UrlName;
        }

        public void setUrlName(String UrlName) {
            this.UrlName = UrlName;
        }

        public int getUrlId() {
            return urlId;
        }

        public void setUrlId(int urlId) {
            this.urlId = urlId;
        }

        public boolean equals(UrlData rData) {
            boolean bEqual = false;
            if (this.getUrlId() > 0 && rData.getUrlId() > 0 && this.getUrlId() == rData.getUrlId()) {
                bEqual = true;
            }
            return bEqual;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good link for you: [How can I get the request URL from a Java Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389596/how-can-i-get-the-request-url-from-a-java-filter)

What I would do is use something like that example and do a set of three URLs.

```
//Using linked example
    public class MyFilter implements Filter {
        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException { }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getPathTranslated();
            UrlBean urlBean = (UrlBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()getApplication().getValueBinding("#{urlBean}");
            urlBean.storeUrl(url);
        }

    public void destroy() { }
}
```

This is totally untested, but the idea should work. You would just need to implement some logic (probably a stack) for your component so it stores what you need. (Obviously you might end up at the same URL multiple times). I should note the UrlBean is just an abstract idea, you would have to implement it

Comment: Thanks Daniel Chapman,
This example looking good, i will try it out and let you know the result.

Comment: Rather than going with above approach i made a Singleton class with a HashMap and added all Url with sessionId as key for Map It worked fine for me.