# Retrieving the REST URL pattern from a servlet filter

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have created a rest service with the following url pattern

```
/author/{authorId}/book/{bookId}
```

In run time I can access the service with the following path

```
/author/1234/book/1001
```

Now I have a `ServletFilter` defined. Every request to access the `url/author/1234/book/1001` is hitting the filter too. In this filter how can I find the url pattern of the incoming request ie, `/author/{authorId}/book/{bookId}`.

Regards
-Albin

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389596/how-can-i-get-the-request-url-from-a-java-filter

Comment: HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()

Comment: @vikeng21 The difference with the other question is I am looking to find the request url pattern instead of the request url.

Answer (score 0):

first find the real path of the request. that is the requested_uri - context_path

```
String uri = req.getRequestURI();
String context = req.getContextPath();
String realPath = uri.substring(context.length());
```

then use regex to extract authorId and bookId

Comment: It does not provide me the url pattern. It gives me the request uri and not the url pattern. The filter that I am writing is generic for a list of services. So I won't be able to use regex to extract the authorId and bookId.