# ADF Security capture request URL before redirection (PagePhaseListener)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf

How can i cupture user Original request URL befor that it'll be redirected to Authentication page.

I try with PagePhaseListener but it is already redirected to Authentication page

```
    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PagePhaseEvent pagePhaseEvent) {


        if (!AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
            HttpServletRequest request =
                (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            System.out.println("ABIn On load context path" + request.getContextPath());
            System.out.println("ABIn On load getRequestURI " + request.getRequestURI());
            System.out.println("ABIn On load getRequestURL " + request.getRequestURL());
            System.out.println("ABIn On load getServletPath " + request.getServletPath());
        }
}
```

It there another listener on top of PagePhaseListener?
How can i deal with this issue?

Comment: Did you try with a filter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389596/how-can-i-get-the-request-url-from-a-java-filter

Comment: I saw it. It doesn't help me because at thsz time the request is already redirected