# Java web.xml - How do I do a catchall servlet for any unmatched requests to forward to index.html?

Tags: java, servlets

I am serving an angular page in a Java WAR in Glassfish.

I need to serve everything under public as a static file and all other requests should serve index.html.

Because it's Angular, it needs to serve index.html but still keep the end. So if you go to example.com/stuff it should load the index page and keep /stuff on the end.

I have this glassfish-web.xml right now, but I'm still getting a 404 for everything outside public.

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD 
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Removed GlassFish because the problem and solution is unrelated to the application server. Similar for *war* and *angularjs* tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Serlvet Filter:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class MainFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        String requestUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        if (validUrl(requestUrl)) {
            //allowed, continue navigation
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            //invalid URL, send back to index.html
            String invaludUrl = retrieveInvalidPart(requestUrl);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.html" + invaludUrl);
        }
    }

    private boolean validUrl(String url) {
        //implement how to validate the URL
    }

    private String retrieveInvalidPart(String url) {
        //implement how to recognize the invalid part of the URL
    }
}
```

Note that this problem is completely unrelated to GlassFish or any other application server.

If you also want/need to add the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) associated to the url in case of invalid request, you may retrieve it by using `HttpServletRequest#getQueryString`:

```
//invalid URL, send back to index.html
String invaludUrl = retrieveInvalidPart(requestUrl);
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
queryString = (queryString == null) ? "" : queryString;
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.html" + "?invalidUrl=" + invaludUrl + queryString);
```

More info:

- [StackOVerflow Servlet Filter Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)
- [How can I get the request URL from a Java Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4389596/1065197)