# Java HttpServletRequest getRequestURL returning instance name instead of domain name

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am running a spring framework based web app on Oracle Weblogic Server.
I have 2 subdomain for my URL pointing to my application (Instance).

For example: [www.asd.com](http://www.asd.com) and secure.asd.com.

From my code I need to identify the subdomain and handle different logics for each subdomain.

```
((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
```

is actually returning machine name instead of full URL.

My expectation

```
secure.asd.com
```

But what I'm getting is (machine name)

```
svmachine001
```

Any idea how to get Full URL?

Comment: The request URL is taken from the URL you used at the client. You must have used `svmachine001`. Solution: don't.

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy like nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getRequestURL()? Here is called from a servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
...
        StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
...
}
```

Tested in WLS 12.2.1.4.

Taken from:
[How can I get the request URL from a Java Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389596/how-can-i-get-the-request-url-from-a-java-filter)